# IsolatedStorageFile.FileExists(string path) works but StreamReader(string samePath) doesn't?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, streamreader, isolatedstorage

`IsolatedStorageFile.FileExists(string path)` works but `StreamReader(string samePath)` doesn't?
I have validated both paths are equal. I have no idea why the StreamReader explodes

```
     List<ProjectObj> ret = new List<ProjectObj>();
     IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

     if (!file.DirectoryExists("/projects/")) //trying to validate the dir exists
         return ret;

     string[] fileNames = file.GetFileNames("/projects/");

     foreach (string filename in fileNames)
     {
        if (!file.FileExists("/projects/" + filename)) //validate just one more time..
            continue;

        ProjectObj tempProj = new ProjectObj();

        //Even with the validation it still breaks right here with the bellow error
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("/projects/"+filename);
```

> An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Message:Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\projects\Title_939931883.txt'.

Answer (score 1):

Give this one a try. Reading and writing files in IsolatedStorage has a different path and should be used like that. You should consider reading [How to: Read and Write to Files in Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf96a1wz.aspx).

```
        public static List<ProjectObj> getProjectsList()
        {
            List<ProjectObj> ret = new List<ProjectObj>();
            IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            if (!file.DirectoryExists("/projects/")) //trying to validate the dir exists
                return ret;

            string[] fileNames = file.GetFileNames("/projects/");

            foreach (string filename in fileNames)
            {
                if (!file.FileExists("/projects/" + filename)) //validate just one more time...
                    continue;

                ProjectObj tempProj = new ProjectObj();

                using (var isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("/projects/" + filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, file))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isoStream))
                    {
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

Comment: I've updated the answer and fixed the code using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415979/operation-not-permitted-on-isolatedstoragefilestream-error

Answer (score 1):

Path is not same in both cases. In `first case` you are getting `User store for application` and then search for file in it. But in `later case` you are simply searching in `base directory`.

`StreamReader` constructor expects `absolute path` of file.

You need to create `IsolatedStorageFileStream` and pass it on to `StreamReader` -

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream =  new IsolatedStorageFileStream
                                ("/projects/" + filename, FileMode.Open, file))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream ))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

Comment: You can do operation on IsolatedStorageFileStream. Refer to this link from MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf96a1wz.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I came up with

```
        List<ProjectObj> ret = new List<ProjectObj>();
        IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        if (!file.DirectoryExists("/projects/"))
            return ret;
        foreach (String filename in file.GetFileNames("/projects/"))
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("/projects/"+filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                String fileInfo = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

I don't know why I was getting the illegal operation on boot of app but I know why it was happening later on. I guess when you try and access the same file to quickly it causes errors. So I added in a fileshare and also I made sure to dispose of other accesses before this ran.