# Issue when Reading xml: "System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream" (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: c#, xml, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, task

I have an issue when reading from an xml file with the object Friend in it!

file.exist() returns true but when he opens storage, an exception is thrown!

```
public static async Task<List<Friend>> Load<Friend>(string file)
{           
    IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    List<Friend> friend = Activator.CreateInstance<List<Friend>>();

    if (storage.FileExists(file))
    {
        IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = null;
        try
        {
            stream = storage.OpenFile(file, FileMode.Open);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Friend>));

            friend = (List<Friend>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return friend;
    }
    return friend;
}
```

Comment: What part of which error don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand where I have to put the await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method doesn't use any asynchronous calls, so it shouldn't be flagged `async`:

```
public static List<Friend> Load(string file) 
{
```

The compiler will warn you because you marked the method asynchronous, and made it return `Task<T>`, but you don't call and await any asynchronous methods, so it will always run synchronously.

Comment: Thanks, that removed the warning! But I still get the message: "System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream"

Comment: @GC268DM See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415979/operation-not-permitted-on-isolatedstoragefilestream-error for more details