# Background Transfer Windows Phone c# (Operation not permitted)

Tags: c#, download, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I've done this example [http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202959(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202959%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
and it works partially.
When I download a file and I stay in the download page it doesn't give any errors but if I go out from the page and then I return, the emulator crashes and give the error: IsolatedStorageException Operation not permitted.
That is a Microsoft example and I can't find any solution.
Thanks,

Mattia

Answer (score 0):

You can not have one stream read and another write at the same time.

The scenario only works when you have something already in the file, and you write to one stream and read the contents of the file at the same time.

Take look over here [Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream. error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415979/)